# Search for city on Google Maps inside Excel Userform on Initialize

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am wondering if it possible to search for specific city on Google Map inside Excel userform once Userform is opened?

Userform has a name `Flights`. It has Web browser with name `WebBrowser1`

Here is my current code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Flights.WebBrowser1.Navigate "https://maps.google.com"

End Sub
```

I have tried:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Flights.WebBrowser1.Navigate "https://maps.google.com"
    Flights.WebBrowser1.Document.getElementsByName("q")(0).Value = "Washington"
    Flights.WebBrowser1.Document.getElementsByClassName("searchbox-searchbutton")(0).Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just navigate to `https://www.google.com/maps?q=washington` or `https://maps.google.com?q=washington`.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Flights.WebBrowser1.Navigate "https://maps.google.com?q=washington"

End Sub
```

alternatively you could try (not tested)

```
With Flights.WebBrowser1
    .Navigate "https://maps.google.com"
    Do While .readyState <> 4 Or .Busy: DoEvents: Loop 'wait until page loads
    .Document.getElementsByName("q")(0).Value = "Washington"
    .Document.getElementsByID("searchbox_form")(0).submit
End With
```

Comment: That's what I call thinking outside the box :) This is solution to my question actually but I would like to see an option to use controls just in case I will need them in the future.

Comment: Ok, this is actually what I have tried already. I just found out that the problem is that if I first open userform and then run `Flights.WebBrowser1.Document.getElementsByName("q")(0).Value = "Washington"` by separate button it works. However if it is like in my code, it seems that page isn't loaded yet when code tries to input value to Google Maps search box. Is there any ideas how to automate the whole thing so there will be no need to click any other buttons?

Comment: Yes you will need to check if the browser is ready and the page is loaded. See my edit. But actually the direct navigate should be a lot faster then filling the form and sending another request.

Comment: Thank you for your help! There is anyway some issue with `UserForm_Initialize` as it is not opening with this code. However everything works by separate button. Maybe computer is not so fast to do all the things on `UserForm_Initialize` and code should be connected to some other process.